# Programming mathemathics: how to expand a function

Tags: math

Lets say that I have a math function that is defined recursively. Like so:

```
T(1)(x) = 1
T(n)(x) = 2x*T(n-1)(x)-1
```

So:

```
T(1)(x) = 1
T(2)(x) = 2x*1-1 = 2x-1
T(3)(x) = 2x*(2x-1)-1 = 4x^2 - 2x - 1
/* and so on... */
```

Basically, I know how to write a program that will count `T(15)(x)` if the `x` is given. Thats not a problem. What I wonder, however is - how to write a program that will give me a polynomial for like T(10)(x) (one looking something like: `16x^4 + 3x^3 ...`).

In the nutshell: How can I recursively count the math expression, but using `x` as a variable (not set).

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Paul

Comment: When you say "count" do you mean "produce" or "create"?  As it stands, I'm not entirely sure what you're asking.

Comment: do you want the program in Mathematica programming language?

Comment: @Yaroslav Just use RSolve ... I think the tag is wrong

Comment: wow, You guys are right, I made a mistake with the tag, didn't know something like Mathematica existed. I would like to eventually write this program in something like C/Java/PHP/C#, not in a Derive, Matlab, Maxima, Mathematica kind of thing.

Comment: "Is there a way to write and Expand() function in C/Java/PHP?" - that is I guess the real question.

Comment: @PawelMysior, that changes things a bit.  Most optimizing compilers can "unroll" a tail-recursive (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_recursion) process, so it may not be necessary to do anything more than adapt what you have already to whatever language you wish to use.  That said, do you want a specific polynomial to use in your code?

Comment: `Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind` to be exact. Function like: cheb_poly(5) should then produce something like here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Examples

Comment: @PawelMysior,obviously, you wish to execute the result, but in most programming environments it won't be expanded, per se.  However, if written correctly, it should run just as fast.  Now, the rest of the answer depends on what you using the polynomials for.

Comment: Well, that's it. I don't want to actually run it with any given `x`. I just want to generate the nth polynomial and render it to the user.

Comment: @PawelMysior, that's a very hard question, and I don't know how to do it beyond tapping into another system entirely, like webMathematica (http://www.wolfram.com/products/webmathematica/) or WolframAlpha (http://www.wolframalpha.com).  The problem is the expansion part of the requirement.  I think I could do something if that wasn't required, though.

Comment: @PawelMysior, would you update your question to reflect the comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon the comments, I believe that there are four options, in order of complexity.

First, you could just implement an explicit formula for the given polynomial that you are looking for, if it exist.  In the case of the Chebyshev polynomials, an [explicit formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Explicit_formulas) (3<sup>rd</sup> sum from the top) fitting your needs does exist.

If, however, you are looking for something more general, i.e. more than one type of polynomial, you could create an explicit list of the polynomials up to some absurd order and do a string replace using the user supplied variable name.  In most systems, this won't take up a lot of memory.

Thirdly, if you wish to remain general and still recursively produce the polynomials, you could tap into a computer algebra system, like Mathematica.  For instance, you can access Mathematica through [MathLink](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/MathLinkAndExternalProgramCommunicationOverview.html), or use an instance of [webMathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/products/webmathematica/), or even scrape the output from [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/).  Although, I think you'd run into copyright issues with the last one.

Lastly, the most complex and most general would be to create an [abstract syntax tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree).  If you can use c++, I'd look at [boost.proto](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/proto.html) which essentially does this for you.  But, if you create it yourself, you'd have three types of binary ops, `add`, `multiply`, and `power` and two types of leaf nodes, `coefficient` and `variable`.  Now, to massage the tree into a form where you can use it you have to move through the tree and apply transformation rules:  replace a subtree and interchange parent and child.  Replace would alter the tree by applying standard math rules, such as 2 + 2 becomes 4 and x * x becomes x<sup>2</sup>.  But, the real work would be in interchanging the parent and child nodes, as this would be used to apply the distributive law (mult -> add becoming add -> mult) and providing opportunities to use replace.

The first two options are by far the easiest, and I'd go with the first if it is available.  That said, I'd find implementing either the MathLink interface or the syntax tree much more interesting to do.

**Edit**: to clarify what I mean by interchanging a parent with its child, consider the case of `n = 2`.

[image: Graphic showing a basic transformation of a expression tree.]

which effects 4 nodes:  "Plus", both "Times", and the coefficient 1.  But, it is easy to see that this will reduce the overall number of nodes by eliminating the second "Times."

Comment: Note: I deleted my first answer as it had nothing to do with what the OP wanted answered.

Answer (score 0):

I think your Mathematica tag may be wrong, but anyway. Mathematica has an embedded function RSolve to cope with this:

```
   RSolve[{a[n] == 2  x a[n - 1] - 1, a[1] == 1}, a[n], n]
```

The result is:

```
   a[n] = (x + 2^n (-1 + x) x^n)/(x (-1 + 2 x))
```

As expected

```
   a[3] = -1 - 2 x + 4 x^2
```

HTH

Comment: I'm not sure he's asking for it to be solved, although, I'm not really sure what he's asking for.  But, I think it is just to generate the nth polynomial.

Comment: rcollyer - generating the nth polynomial - exactly what I want to achieve.

Comment: @PawelMysior the a[n] in the answer is the polynomial